# How to add custom compilation output to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, qooxdoo

I'm one of the developers of [QxCompiler](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo-compiler), a node-based javascript compiler and linter for the [Qooxdoo project](https://www.qooxdoo.org/).  Like any compiler, it outputs a series of errors and warnings with line numbers but at the moment this is only output to the console.  As a developer, you can Alt-Tab round to read the output but it's easy to forget to do that and it would be very useful to use Eclipse's existing code marker system to show the list of errors and highlight them in the source code.

How do I output this to Eclipse so that it will incorporate the errors and warnings into the source code?

What would be really useful is if there is some kind of IDE-neutral standard for formatting the output of the compiler so that it'll work on more than just Eclipse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here some thoughts:

#### LSP

If you are interested in bringing up output into multiple IDEs in a neutral way, you should refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol where LSP is described. As far as I know it can be used for code completion, outline support etc. Maybe it will fit your requirements.

#### Eclipse Log plugin

Another option is to send the output to a log file and use plugin for log files in eclipse..

#### Do as done in `Jenkins Editor` eclipse plugin

You could also provide a REST API and maybe even a CLI tool. This is how jenkins linter works. There is a `jenkins editor` plugin for eclipse which does use the CLI tool (REST API) to bring up messages and errors into the eclipse editor.
See https://github.com/de-jcup/eclipse-jenkins-editor/blob/master/jenkins-editor-plugin/src/main/java-eclipse/de/jcup/jenkinseditor/handlers/CallLinterHandler.java for an entry point to look into sources and how it was done.

*Some addititional explanations can be found at https://github.com/de-jcup/eclipse-jenkins-editor/wiki/Validate-by-Jenkins-Linter*

Comment: that's great, thank you - LSP looks like the way to go

Comment: For eclipse LSP4e 1.0.0 is planned for 2019-06-27, see https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.lsp4e